# Chrome extension causes problems with jquery and javascript on some pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a small chrome extension which I want to use to change text. It works just the way I want it to(clicking the icon changes text), but on some pages the existing jquery stops working when the app is enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Files:  manifest.json, myscript.js and background.html

manifest.json content:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

myscript.js content:

```
var array = {"not":" NOT ", "like":" LIKE ", "job":"JOBS"}

for (var val in array)
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(val, "g"),     array[val]);
```

background.html content:

```
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                       {file:"myscript.js"});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body.innerHTML` is very bad.

When you use it, you're treating DOM nodes as raw text. Those DOM nodes have event handlers and even a simple `document.body.innerHTML+='...'` will send the existing nodes to oblivion, creating new ones, without event handlers.

So instead, you need to iterate through all the text nodes in the document [(*see here how)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367986/how-to-get-all-textnodes-in-html-document-from-specific-tags-using-javascript) and do an innerHTML each one individually.

Sănătate!